# Passing a function from a react component to its parent then from the parent to another child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component named **Products**, and it has this function declared in it:

```
const filterBySearch = (value: string) => {
    setAllProducts((prevProducts) => {
        const filtered = sourceProducts.filter((product) =>
            product.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
        );
        return filtered;
    });
};
```

I also have 2 other components, **Navbar**, and **App**, the **Navbar** contains a search input field, I want things to work in a way that whenever the value of that input inside the **Navbar** changes, the **FilterBySearch** function is called with the input value as its argument.
The problem is that **Navbar** is neither a child of **Products** nor a parent, but they're both children of the **App** component.
How do I pass the **FilterBySearch** from **Products** to **App** then from **App** to **Navbar** ?

Comment: You _could_, for example, expose the search string in a context provided by `App`: `NavBar` triggers an event `onSearchChange` and updates the state; in `Products` you could `useEffect()` on that value (you _might_ not even use a context and simply pass the property down). Alternatively you _could_ add define the search bar in `Products` (show it with a portal, get a `ref` to `NavBar`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than passing the function you can set up the filterBySearch function inside the **App** component with the products state and call the function inside the **Navbar** component inside the change event listener of the input element.

Next, pass the *allProducts* state to the **Products** components

```js
const App = () => {
    const [allProducts, setAllProducts] = useState([]);
    const filterBySearch = (value: string) => {
        setAllProducts((prevProducts) => {
            const filtered = sourceProducts.filter((product) =>
                product.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
            );
            return filtered;
        });
    };
    return (
        <Navbar filterBySearch={filterBySearch}  />
        <Products allProducts={products} />
    )
}

const Navbar = ({filterBySearch}) => {
    return <input onChange={(e) => filterBySearch(e.target.value)} />
}

const Products = ({allProducts}) => {
    //...
}
```

**Or**

You can define the function inside the **Navbar** component and pass the *setAllProducts* function as a prop to the **Navbar** component

```js
const App = () => {
    const [allProducts, setAllProducts] = useState([]);
    
    return (
        <Navbar setAllProducts={setAllProducts}  />
        <Products allProducts={products} />
    )
}

const Navbar = ({setAllProducts}) => {
    const filterBySearch = (value: string) => {
        setAllProducts((prevProducts) => {
            const filtered = sourceProducts.filter((product) =>
                product.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
            );
            return filtered;
        });
    };
    return <input onChange={(e) => filterBySearch(e.target.value)} />
}

const Products = ({allProducts}) => {
    //...
}
```

Comment: i might go with the 1st method, i should define sourcePorducts in the app component aswell right?

Comment: Yes. You can either define it as a variable in the **App** component or pass it as an argument to the *filterBySeach* function from the **Navbar** component. I'd prefer defining it inside the app component over passing it as an argument because I'll be able to use it inside the **Products** component anytime by passing it as a prop